# How to find level 1, level 2, level 3 ...level N managers for an employee

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table Employee with User_Id,Name,Manager_Id (references user_id ).

I need to find the manager, manager of manager, manager of manager of... till root user for a particular employee.

I can do this recursively by finding one manager then proceeding with that employee,but, I was wondering if there is another efficient way/query for this.

Recursive solution will not be feasible since I require as few db hits as possible.

Comment: Is there a logical maximum? I.e. can you say that it will _never_ exceed 5 levels for example? This is pertinent to a single-call solution

Comment: Currently, the level is limited to **Maximum** 5. But we are planning to go with a flat hierarchy also where an employee of L1 can be the manager of another Employee at L2. This will remove ay logical max.

Comment: How do the results for this appear?  Is each manager in their own row, or does it all appear as separate columns (or a single column) in one row?

Comment: There should be separate row for every manager

Comment: You will get your solution here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27775/loop-through-self-join-on-table-until-the-operand-column-is-null-completely

Comment: What version of MySQL? It matters because v8 and above, and MariaDB v10.1 and above have recursive common table expressions allowing you to do this in a single query.

Comment: Mysql 5.7 is being used.